# What is the plural of 'Kraken'?

Tags: irregular-plurals

What is the plural of Kraken, the sea monster? It is a word not listed in any dictionary.

Issues:

- The word has a Teutonic feel and so might be inflected like German plurals, so 'Kraken' (a null plural)
- The word is now part of English and should be pluralized exactly like all other normal English words: 'Krakens'.
- If the word came from Greek mythology, to be true to ancient Greek, the plural would be 'Kraka', 'Krakagma', or 'Krakatoa'.
- They could be conjugated like sheep, fish, and deer, or like like lions, tigers, and bears.
- They (whichever plural is used) don't exist.
- Not existing doesn't stop people from making up names or from being styled grammatically.
- There is only one Kraken so there is no need to ever talk about more than one.
- Not having more than one doesn't stop people from imagining a second or from being styled grammatically.
- [It is a word listed in a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kraken):

  > kraken noun
  >   kra·​ken | \ ˈkrä-kən  \
  >   plural krakens or kraken
  >   : a fabulous Scandinavian sea monster

So, of

> The Kraken were released

or

> The Krakens were released

which is it?

---

Side question: what is the term of venery (collective term) for Kraken? A school of Kraken? A herd of Kraken? A catastrophe of Kraken?

Comment: "It is a word not listed in any dictionary". To the contrary, [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104431) gives: "1771   C. Douglas in *Philos. Trans. 1770* (Royal Soc.) 60 41   Enquiry..as to the existence of the aquatic animals, called **Kraakens**." [emphasis mine]  So in addition to *your own* dictionary citation, the OED citation makes the premise of your question unclear.

Comment: I'm very confused. You start your question out with "It is a word not listed in any dictionary." and then a few sentences later you directly contradict yourself by saying "It is a word listed in a dictionary". Which is it? And moreover, why does the Merriam-Webster assertion that both "kraken" and "krakens" are acceptable not answer your question?

Comment: *Krakatoa!?* So the explosion in Indonesia in 1883 was a mating ritual or something?

Comment: There is only one Kraken, so a plural is not needed :)

Comment: @Smock Thanks. I forgot to add that.

Comment: What's the issue? You've answered your own question *in the question.* Merriam-Webster gives both *Kraken* and *Krakens*. Your question should end here. Moreover, Many English words follow this *exact* pattern. Do you disagree with M-W?

Comment: My wife who speaks Norwegian might say "Kraker" -- "Kraken" is "the Krak", and "er" creates a plural.  (But of course you should never say "a Kraken" or "the Kraken".)

Comment: @HotLicks Research has shown that in Norwegian, 'kraken' is 'the' krake' and the plural of krake' is 'kraker' as your wife might say.

Comment: The point about the Greek endings (apart from somehow ending up in an Indonesian island) seem rather redundant since _kraken_ is not a Greek word – in fact, there are no Greek noun declensions which contain _-en_ as a possible ending, and _kraken_ simply **cannot** be a Greek word. @HotLicks You would, however, say “this kraken”, since Norwegian double-marks deictics with definite forms. And the definite plural would of course be _krakene_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are, in general, two ways to form plurals of foreign words
in English: to use English rules, or to uses the rules of the
original language. This gives us two choices and we have to
choose between them.

By English rules, there is no dispute that the plural is
*Krakens*.

To determine the original form, we first have to determine the
original language, which commenters on this site, and online
references, agree is Norwegian. The commenters that have
knowledge of Norwegian have pointed out that *Kraken* is a
definite form. Unfortunately anyone with no knowledge of North
Germanic languages will be stuck at this point, so I shall try to
explain. Originally, i.e. in Old Norse, there were two equivalent
ways of using the definite article. I am not going to give an
example in Old Norse for a word that did not exist in Old Norse,
but it is as if you could say either *en Krake* or *Kraken*,
interchangeably, to mean “the Kraken”. (And yes, *Krake* is
the original singular.) As Old Norse developed into Modern
Norwegian, the article coalesced with the ending of the word to
give what they now call the definite form. Thus we have

| Norwegian | English |
| --- | --- |
| *Krake* | *Kraken* |
| *Kraken* | *the Kraken* |
| *Kraker* | *Krakens* |
| *Krakene* | *the Krakens* |

although this does vary by dialect. So, since *Kraken* is not the
Norwegian for English *Kraken*, it is rather difficult to use
Norwegian as a model for the English plural!

So how did this error occur? Clearly the main problem is that
most English speakers do not speak Norwegian, but we can point to
something more specific. It is quite normal to fail to recognise
an article in another language. The most common example of this
is the large number of words in English that begin with *al‑*
that come from Arabic, where *al* is simply Arabic for “the”.
No one ever attempts to use Arabic plurals for these words and it
is obvious why. Anyone who can say *the alcohols* clearly does
not know what *al* means, and can thus hardly be expected to know
what the correct Arabic plural is.

Thus there is no satisfactory way to use a Norwegian plural, so
we had better stick to *Krakens*. There is certainly no logic
behind the use of *Kraken* as the plural of itself. This may have
come about from people trying to use their knowledge of German to
work out the plural.

Comment: So what do I do with all these kroner?

Comment: Thank you, @HotLicks for an excellent example of what the plural would be if the singular were *Krake*! The reason the mistake has occurred with *Kraken* and not with *krone* is presumably because *Kraken* is usually definite whereas we usually talk about money using indefinite forms. (And the complexity of how to say specifically "these kroner" in Norwegian is taking things a bit far, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Oxford dictionary defines **Kraken** and uses the plural of Kraken in an example sentence,

> ‘Dragons, **krakens**, giant serpents, griffins, hippogriffs, ogres, evil giants, hydras, and beasts that bore no name at all were among the forces.’

Citation from the book: [The Journey to Krakens Cave By Sheridan Injeeli](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NR6-AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&dq=%22Krakens%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjthqzZ5bbhAhXJYisKHQZfCFUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Krakens%22&f=false) uses the plural form **Krakens**.

> > The spell was supposed to grant a wish of any desire, when the Kraken passed away, it's skull was left behind, Legend has it that the skull was located and hidden in the **Krakens** cave.

Also, there are multiple books using the plural form as [**Krakens**.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="Krakens")

---

On your auxiliary question: `herd of Krakens` or group of Krakens. I'll say herd of Krakens **can be said** as- ***Squad of Krakens*** on the premises that a giant squid 
was misunderstood as a kraken- a mythical creature. Description of Kraken is given by [Erik Pontoppidan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erik_Pontoppidan).

From [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Kraken),

> The popular notion of the kraken dates back at least to the time of Pontoppidan (1698-1764), who wrote a description of it. **One of the giant squids**, as a cephalopod of the genus Architeuthis, ***might furnish a reasonable basis for the myth.***

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kraken)
there are two plural forms:

***krakens*** or ***kraken***.

But the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kraken%20were%2C%20Krakens&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKrakens%3B%2Cc0) gives only the *first* form.

Comment: Google NGrams is notoriously a difficult tool to use properly. Consider choosing the context differently.

Comment: You’re comparing apples to apples and a verb. When you include *were* on the other side too neither of them show any results in ngram

Comment: If you ditch "were" from your search terms, you'll find that there are results for both the singular and plural forms.

Answer (score 1):

The OP says:

> Side question: what is the term of venery (collective term) for
>   Kraken? A school of Kraken? A herd of Kraken? A catastrophe of Kraken?

My answer addresses this part of the OP's question.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kraken) defines kraken as:

> a  legendary   sea   monster   **causing   large   whirlpools**   off
>   the   coast  of  Norway. (emphasis added.)

Thus, the term of venery should be:

> A turbulence of krakens.

A whirlpool is an example of turbulent flow.  See the picture at [Wikipedia, whirlpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool).  Several whirlpools formed by several kraken close together would be even more turbulent.